fullcalendar v6 cdn script initialisation event sources format ics not loading
I am trying to load ics files in fullcalendar I inserted on my html page via script tags from the premium bundle scheduler as of the official documentation https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals#premium-bundle
Now I want to load events from public ics files with this sample code. Unfortunately as you can see in the code snippet, no holiday is displaying from any of the 2 public ics files and no error in my console is displaying.
What am I missing in my code to make the holidays appear in the calendar?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@6.1.15/index.global.min.js'></script>
    <script>
          document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
                initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                locale: 'fr',
                buttonText: {
                    today: 'Aujourd’hui',
                    day: 'jour',
                    week:'semaine',
                    month:'mois'
                },
                eventSources: [
                    {
                    url: "https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays/england-and-wales.ics",
                    format: "ics",
                    },
                    {
                        url: 'https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/fr.french%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics',
                        format: 'ics'
                    }
                ]                
            });
            calendar.render();
          });
    
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </body>
</html>



Merci pour votre aide

As per the events from an iCalendar feed documentation, using this feature requires fullCalendar's icalendar and the 3rd-party ical.js packages to be installed. And as per the premium bundle documentation which you already referenced, those packages aren't included in the bundle. So you'd need to add the script tags for those into your page, for a start

BUT, once you do that you'll hit a 2nd problem which is that Google's ICS feeds don't allow CORS requests by default, so the requests fullCalendar sends for those ICS files will fail (demo - https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/dPbWXEo - watch the console and network tools as the page is loading). I think you'd have to register yourself with a google account, get an API key, and then use fullCalendar's google calendar plugin instead, to try and fetch the calendars (I think it'll still work even though those aren't your account's calendars, but you'll have to try it).

Thank you @ADyson these are the two scripts I was missing in my CDN logic
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ical.js/0.0.3/ical.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/icalendar@6.1.15/index.global.min.js"></script>

AND of course the right to use the given ics.
